# How to copy qt source files to my project and let them compile pass?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4.7

In my project, I use QWizard and QWizardPages, but at last I found these classes have too much restrict, and I want to modify their source code. But I think it's not a good idea to directly modify qt source, but copy them to my project folder and rename the class names. Is their somebody do the same thing before? I can't compile the files successfully, it seems qMywizard.cpp include the generated moc file of qMywizard.h at the end, and the moc file can't be compile without the QMyWizardPrivate definition. I'm also afraid that many macros can't be recognized when files change location. Can anyone give me some advice?

Comment: Can't you inherit the classes, and overload/override the member functions you need to modify?

Comment: @Joachim: That's usually not possible, as Qt classes are structured with an internal, private data class where all decisions are made. The Qt classes are merely facades, which you could override, but you can't win anything by this. There still is no access to the actual algorithms.

Comment: @joachim-pileborg: Actually I wrote a class inherited QWizard, but there are so much trouble. For instance, I want to control the <enable/disable/show/hide> properties of wizard buttons, but Qwizard will update their status every time entering a new page, that's boring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qt source is in git. Clone it, make a branch, write your modifications there and compile it with their build system. Also, make sure to understand and follow the license obligations on modifications (especially if you are using the LGPL).

Comment: How to compile with their own build system if I can't do any modification in QT folder? and, does it mean I can't copy files to my own project folder by LGPL?

Comment: Just read the license please. As I said, clone their git repo (http://qt.gitorious.org/) and work in that folder. If you don't understand all of what I'm saying then I suggest sit down and learn if you want to accomplish your goal.

Comment: This is certainly a valid way to go, just be aware of the implications. If you decide later to update to a newer version of Qt, YOU will be responsible for making sure the changes merge together cleanly and that everything still works as you expect. If it were me, I'd put some serious thought into Joachim's suggestion first.